# How can i update or reset my password without entering email field in laravel-8?

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-mail

i have some users in my usertable ,when ever i sent to reset token to my mail based on that mail i am updating my user account password(reset-password)that's working fine but when i want to update my password i need to pass these fields (password,password_confirmation,resetToken,email)[[How i am passing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqLR4.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqLR4.png).what i need is when ever i want to update/reset my password it should get updated without passing email. how can i acheive this thing(without email i want to update), please help me
`ChangePasswordController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdatePasswordRequest;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\User;

class ChangePasswordController extends Controller
{
    public function passwordResetProcess(UpdatePasswordRequest $request){
        return $this->updatePasswordRow($request)->count() > 0 ? $this->resetPassword($request) : $this->tokenNotFoundError();
      }
  
      // Verify if token is valid
      private function updatePasswordRow($request){
         return DB::table('password_resets')->where([
            'email' => $request->email,
             'token' => $request->resetToken
         ]);
      }
  
      // Token not found response  
      private function tokenNotFoundError() {
          return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Either your email or token is wrong.'
          ],Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
      }
  
      // Reset password
      private function resetPassword($request) {
          // find email
          $userData = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();
          // update password
          $userData->update([
            'password'=>bcrypt($request->password)
          ]);
          // remove verification data from db
          $this->updatePasswordRow($request)->delete();
  
          // reset password response
          return response()->json([
            'data'=>'Password has been updated.'
          ],Response::HTTP_CREATED);
      } 
}
```

`UpdatePasswordRequest.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdatePasswordRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email'=>'required|email',
             'password'=>'required|confirmed|required|regex:/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{6,}$/'
        ];
    }
}
```

`password reset table(Migration table)`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePasswordResetsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('password_resets');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you already have the resetToken... so basically you could use that to get de user id and update their password

Comment: You have set email `required`, did you check validation error.

Comment: Hello @FaizanAli if i removed required validation for email also means it's not working ,{
    "error": "Either your email or token is wrong."
} i am getting like this

Comment: Did you added csrf token in you header meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend my solution for your case.
Firstly you should override existing reset link generation method like below;

add below code inside AuthServiceProvider.php inside boot method.

```
ResetPassword::createUrlUsing(function ($user, string $token) {
        return env('APP_URL').'/reset-password/'.$token.'?email='.$user->email;
    });
```

Now you can grap user email easily from reset url. --`request('email')`

Put that inside reset-password form;

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="{{ $email }}" />
```

It's done. Now your users can reset their password without entering email.